# Telegram бот, проблема с запуском с командной строки

Tags: python, telegram-bot, cmd, anaconda, prompt

Возникла проблема, в anaconda prompt команда

> python C:\путь\к\файлу\Bot.py

отлично выполняется и бот работает, а в cmd зависает без сообщения об ошибке, и бот не работает. Также удивительно, что какая-то простенькая программка ( не бот ), как например `print("hello world")` отлично запускается как с cmd так и с anaconda prompt.

Comment: Виртуальное окружение при запуске с cmd используете? Возможно на "голом питоне" или в виртуальном окружении не установлены нужные пакеты, в отличие от анаконды?

Comment: Виртуальное окружение не использую, команда <where python> в cmd и в anaconda prompt возвращает одинаковый результат ( C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\python.exe ).

Comment: Выполните команду `pip freeze` в cmd и anaconda. Есть ли в anaconda пакеты, которые отсутствуют в cmd?